# Prove or refute that language $L=\{a^{n}b^{m}c^{{m}\choose{n}}\}$ is regular

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata

I'm little confused with proving if this language is regular: $L=\{a^{n}b^{m}c^{{m}\choose{n}}\}$. What are $n,m$? Are they arbitrary? If yes, this language has only one word and I need to prove or refute that exists FA that accepts this word?

Comment: Usually this kind of notation is for all $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$, that is $L = \{a^nb^mc^{m \choose n} \mid n,m \in \mathbb{N} \}$. Now, ask yourself what technique you have to show that a language is not regular and how could it be applied here.

Comment: @holf are you sure that $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$? Because I have to prove another language $L=\{2^{n}1^{n}0^{3n}|n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and there is defined $n$.

Comment: Without the clarification @holf gave, the problem really doesn't make much sense as stated.